# get info from london2012 like do google

Tags: web-services, api

I'm trying develop some app related to the Olympic Games.

Does anybody know how get info from the page www.london2012.com, like google does in results?
Does an API exist? Where can I find an API?
I'd suppose, maybe it could be done with a url like:

> www.london2012.com?country=12

(This isn't real, just what I suppose an API might look like)

When I search "london olympics" for example, I see a "gadget" which shows some results, and I believe that these come from www.london2012.com. Does anyone know if that's true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which programming language you are using, making it hard to provide an appropriate answer. I doubt www.london2012.com has produced an API just for access, so you will need to make queries (like you said in your post). For example, if you are using Python, you can use the urllib module to write your requests.

However, be warned. I just read over the www.london2012.com Terms of Service (http://www.london2012.com/terms-of-use/) , and you may not use this information for non-personal use.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible though probably not allowed (see terms of service of the website).

You need your app to make a HTTP call to the page URL and parse the HTML response. Obviously the way to do it depends heavily on the language/technology you use, which you did not indicate in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The Olympics use a system called ODF - Olympic Data Feed to distribute real time statistics from games to authorized parties, usually in XML format. These authorized parties consist of accredited world news organizations (so, yeah, google counts), Rights holding broadcasters (broadcasters that pay to have the rights to distrute Olympics content - NBC in US, BBC in UK, etc, etc) and international sports federations. They have dictionaries listed [here](http://odf.olympictech.org/2016-Rio/rio_2016_OG.htm) - but you can't access it unless you are one of the authorized parties above. So perhaps going the python or some other web scraping route is best.